# Remove h1 take from logo

Tags: html, heading

I'm trying to remove the Heading Tag from the logo and site title on my Website but don't know how to proceed.

```
  <header id="header" class="show-on-scroll" data-offset-el=".index-section" data-offset-behavior="bottom" role="banner">
    <div class="header-inner">
      {.section website}<div id="{.if logoImageUrl}logoWrapper{.or}siteTitleWrapper{.end}" class="wrapper" data-content-field="site-title">
        {.section logoImageUrl}
          <h1 id="logoImage"><a href="/"><img src="{logoImageUrl}?format=1500w" alt="{siteTitle}" /></a></h1>
        {.or}
          <h1 id="siteTitle" class="site-title"><a href="/">{siteTitle}</a></h1>
        {.end}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “remove the heading tag”? Does removing all `<h1 …>` and `</h1>` not do it?

Comment: I was referring to the H1 yes. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `h1` tag from your markup.

```
<header id="header" class="show-on-scroll" data-offset-el=".index-section" data-offset-behavior="bottom" role="banner">
    <div class="header-inner">
      {.section website}<div id="{.if logoImageUrl}logoWrapper{.or}siteTitleWrapper{.end}" class="wrapper" data-content-field="site-title">
        {.section logoImageUrl}
          <div id="logoImage"><a href="/"><img src="{logoImageUrl}?format=1500w" alt="{siteTitle}" /></a></div>
        {.or}
          <div id="siteTitle" class="site-title"><a href="/">{siteTitle}</a></div>
        {.end}
```